# Common practices for testing with ClojureScript using Leiningen?

Tags: testing, clojurescript

I am trying to understand what would be the common practices for writing test code in ClojureScript. I have 3 general questions (one that actually could also apply to Clojure)

1. [Clojure Also]: Any common practices for putting test code in the same source file as your actual code? Most cases that I see, everybody separates test code in a segregated directory. Or it is considered bad practice?
2. What would be the recommended practices for testing within leiningen? I have found at least two variations
   a. The [recommendation from cljsbuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/blob/1.1.6/doc/TESTING.md). Seems to require adding a bit of boilerplate

   b. The one from [ClojureScript Unraveled](http://funcool.github.io/clojurescript-unraveled/#unit-testing). This seems to me a bit out of sync with a figwheel approach
3. The questions above could be split in browser dependent (i.e. requiring PhantomJS) and not browser dependent, so I suspect the best practices might differ a little bit.

I would like to have an understanding of what would be the pitfalls that more seasoned ClojureScript programmers would suggest avoiding. And maybe if there are any best practices?

Thanks